# Ansible to Cisco IOS via SSH, with "authentication failed" message

Tags: ssh, ansible, cisco

Here is a very simple ansible case which bothered me a lot.

This is the content of ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
transport = paramiko
hostfile = ./hosts
host_key_checking = False
timeout = 5
```

the content of hosts, all with a user named "cisco" and password of "cisco" too

```
[routers]
R1
R2
R3
...
```

the host variable file (R1), similar to R2, R3, ..., just different in IP addresses:

```
---
ansible_ssh_host: 10.10.10.1
ansible_ssh_user: cisco
ansible_ssh_pass: cisco
```

I can successfully SSH to those routers via linux, but when I use ansible, it resulted in "authentication failed":

```
fatal: [R1] => {'msg': 'FAILED: Authentication failed.', 'failed': True}
fatal: [R2] => {'msg': 'FAILED: Authentication failed.', 'failed': True}
...
```

and I tested the connectivity with some one line ansible commands, still getting errors even when I input the username and password manually, for example:

```
> ansible routers -m raw
R1 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.
R2 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.    

> ansible routers -u cisco -m raw
R1 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.
R2 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.

> ansible routers -u cisco -m raw -k
SSH password:
R1 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.
R2 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.
```

How can I solve this? helps will be appreciated.

Comment: I finally figured it out by checking the full log (paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG), paramiko will finish the connection if public key authentication failed, rather than keep trying password. So when using paramiko, the parameter "look_for_keys" in method "connect()" MUST be set to False

Comment: After setting look_for_keys=False, all is fine

Comment: can you answer your own question with a bit detail so that it will help others. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Python interpreter [connect() for paramiko connections](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.2/api/client.html) can be used like this:

> `connect(hostname, port=22, username=None, password=None, pkey=None, key_filename=None, timeout=None, allow_agent=True, look_for_keys=True, compress=False, sock=None, gss_auth=False, gss_kex=False, gss_deleg_creds=True, gss_host=None, banner_timeout=None, auth_timeout=None)`
>
> […]
>
> **look_for_keys** (bool) – set to False to disable searching for discoverable private key files in `~/.ssh/`

Comment: For clarity, Arbab Nazar wasn't looking for the answer; they were *asking for it to be clearly written up for the sake of posterity*, the goal of SO. I've tried to adjust this answer for better clarity. If you can add more of an explanation that would also be appreciated.